# AWS opswork stack attributes cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am passing my 3rd party subscription license key (newrelic) and few other config variables via the stack settings `Custom JSON`.

```
"opsworks_java": {
   "datasources": {
     "app": "jdbc/myapp"
   }
},
"newrelic": {
    "license": "2454645aef2e055a1f5fc0e2201f5570bccaa3deb3"
}
```

After I change the value of these attributes or add new keys, I run `configure` recipes on my already existing instances, hoping that it will pick up the new stack settings JSON, but it doesnt work. Am I missing something?

**PS**. I am new to Opswork , so probably there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `update_cookbooks` on already existing instances (or do a deploy). (Stack -> Run Command)

Here's an experiment: do *new* instances read these values correctly / configure themselves with these values? If so, `update_cookbooks` should help you out.